# Polytomous RASH model in R or SAS

Tags: r

I am working on the RASH modeling in R as well as SAS, and I have item parameters and need to calculate persons score. While looking in to SAS it was not so easy hence was looking in R, Could anyone suggest a R package for polytomous RASH model?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the eRm or pcIRT package.

below is the reference for the package.

[eRM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eRm/vignettes/eRm.pdf)

[pcIRT](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pcIRT/pcIRT.pdf)